# Direct2D equivalent of GDI InvertRect

Tags: winapi, gdi, direct2d

I need to convert GDI methods calls of a relatively complex program into equivalent Direct2D code. For most of the GDI functions I could write equivalent code. But I haven't found any equivalent code for InvertRect. Since the drawing is done dynamically, I can't create (or it will be a performance bottleneck) WICBitmap to get pixels and invert the color.

Can anyone suggest me a good solution, please?

Comment: Right, that's exactly why you can't find the equivalent, Direct2D doesn't want to do this expensive thing either.  Restructure your drawing code so you can reproduce those pixels, but now with a different set of colors.  As a bonus it should be much more pleasing to the eye, given the often awful colors that InvertRect() produces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invert an area that's already been drawn, I believe you can use `CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Flood)` to create an effect that fills with a solid color, then set the effect's color parameter to white, and then use `ID2D1DeviceContext::DrawImage` with that effect and use `D2D1_COMPOSITE_MODE_XOR` for the `compositeMode` parameter.

(You may also need to use *transparent white*, now that I think of it ... assuming that XOR also operates on the alpha channel. You may need to experiment. Also, it may not work, I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [Direct2D Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d2d1_1/nn-d2d1_1-id2d1effect).

There are [Built-in Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Direct2D/built-in-effects) and you can use the [Invert effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Direct2D/invert-effect).